# Android forms previewer renderer instead of the usual preview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I just created a mobile app with xamarin.forms and I wanted to start, by making the navigation of the application. Upon creating a content page the previewer ends up not showing anything, apart from a text saying:

> Android forms previewer renderer instead of the usual preview.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I have the nugets all updated.

[image: Image of what is happening]

Comment: have you built the project?  tried restarting VS?

Comment: yes i have and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of stuff I ended up creating like 5 or more projects and somehow the previewer on the last on is working but on the other ones it just ain't.